# Can I delete a commit in a pending Pull Request

Tags: git, github

I sent in a PR to a remote repo and discovered I had the commit from a previous PR included is it possible to delete this unwanted commit?

Comment: You should be able to decline the pull request from the GitHub UI.

Comment: Thanks I'm using github cli

Comment: Do you want to delete a _commit_ in a pull request, or the pull request itself?

Comment: A commit in the pull request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a `revert` commit for unwanted commits. In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-most-recent-commits-in-git) should be enough info.

Comment: Thanks, but that solution is for when the commit has not been pushed I already pushed still doesn't matter?

Comment: it doesn't. It will be added as additional commit that reverses chosen commits code.

Answer (score 1):

Under your repository name, click  Pull requests.
In the "Pull Requests" list, click the pull request you'd like to close.
At the bottom of the pull request, below the comment box, click Close pull request.

Then to revert the last commit or revert to the SHA of the commit ,you can use the command
git revert HEAD~1 or
git revert  (get the commit id from git log)

Answer (score 0):

You may [close a pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/closing-a-pull-request/) from the GitHub website:

> You may choose to close a pull request without merging it into the upstream branch. This can be handy if the changes proposed in the branch are no longer needed, or if another solution has been proposed in another branch.

1. Under your repository name, click  Pull requests.
2. In the "Pull Requests" list, click the pull request you'd like to close.
3. The close Pull Request buttonAt the bottom of the pull request, below the comment box, click Close pull request.
4. Optionally, delete the branch. This keeps the list of branches in your repository tidy.

Answer (score 0):

You can rebase your branch and update your pull request. Take a look to this [**link**](https://ncona.com/2011/07/how-to-delete-a-commit-in-git-local-and-remote/) and it'll help to how to remove the commit